# How to read Rich Text email in Gmail

Tags: outlook, gmail, richtext, tnef

I'm trying to receive rich text format email from outlook to my gmail (tnef formatted). Gmail is converting these emails. If anyone know about this please comment or answer. I need to view those emails in gmail.